# Android location updates while moving

Tags: android, location

I am making an application which determines the distance between the user's location and the destinations location. Everytime the onLocationChanged method is being called the distance between position A and position B is being recalculated with the distanceTo method from the location class. The distance is then displayed in a textview to the user. The problem I'm facing is how to register the LocationManager in order to receive regular updates with high accuracy. If I only request updates from GPS provider the callbacks are to irregular, even if it's registered with 0 min time and 0 min distance. If I use Network provider the accuracy is too far off. What I want to achieve is every 10th second the textview is updated with an accurate distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If accuracy is the most important issue, then you'll have to rely on the GPS provider.  Are you testing where you expect the phone to be, such as a car?  Keep in mind that lots of things can affect the GPS signal.

If updates are more important then another option is to register to receive updates from both providers.  If you receive 2 updates in your 10 second window, then use the one that is most accurate.